# C++/CLI code doesn't enter .then part of the create_task function

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, c++-cli, video-streaming, task

This is the code that I have:

```
void MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
XTRACE(L"=========================================will start onNavigated ");
    auto mediaCapture = ref new Windows::Media::Capture::MediaCapture();
    m_mediaCaptureMgr = mediaCapture;
    IAsyncAction ^asyncAction = m_mediaCaptureMgr->InitializeAsync();
try
{
    create_task(asyncAction).then([this](task<void> initTask)
    {
        XTRACE(L"=========================================will start onNavigated 2");
        try
        {
            initTask.get();

            auto mediaCapture = m_mediaCaptureMgr.Get();
            if (mediaCapture->MediaCaptureSettings->VideoDeviceId != nullptr && mediaCapture->MediaCaptureSettings->AudioDeviceId != nullptr)
            {
                String ^fileName;
                fileName = VIDEO_FILE_NAME;
                XTRACE(L"=================================Device initialized successful\n");
                create_task(KnownFolders::VideosLibrary->CreateFileAsync(fileName, Windows::Storage::CreationCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName))
                    .then([this](task<StorageFile^> fileTask)
                {
                    XTRACE(L"=================================Create record file successful\n");
                    m_recordStorageFile = fileTask.get();
                    MediaEncodingProfile^ recordProfile = nullptr;
                    recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile::CreateMp4(Windows::Media::MediaProperties::VideoEncodingQuality::Auto);
                    stream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
                    return m_mediaCaptureMgr->StartRecordToStreamAsync(recordProfile, stream);
                }).then([this](task<void> recordTask)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        recordTask.get();
                        XTRACE(L"=================================Start Record successful\n");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ^e)
                    {

                        XTRACE(L"======ERRROR is : %d", e);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {

                XTRACE(L"=================================No VideoDevice/AudioDevice Found\n");
            }
            XTRACE(L"=================================WILL EXIT \n");

        }
        catch (Exception ^ e)
        {
            XTRACE(L"============================================ERROR IS: %d\n", e);
        }
    }
    );

}
catch (Exception ^ e)
{
    XTRACE(L"============================================before create task ERROR IS: %d\n", e);
}
XTRACE(L"=================================SLEEP 20000====================================\n");
std::chrono::milliseconds dura(20000);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
XTRACE(L"=================================TIME ENDED====================================\n");
// stop device detection
try
{
    XTRACE(L"=================================Stopping Record\n");
    create_task(m_mediaCaptureMgr->StopRecordAsync())
        .then([this](task<void> recordTask)
    {
        try
        {
            recordTask.get();
            XTRACE(L"=================================Stop record successful: %d\n", stream->Size);
        }
        catch (Exception ^e)
        {
            XTRACE(L"=================================ERROR while stoping 2:  %d\n", e);
        }
    });
}
catch (Exception ^e)
{
    XTRACE(L"=================================ERROR try catch 3 stoping:  %d\n", e);
}

CloseHandle(ghEvent);

// destruct the device manager
XTRACE(L"=====================================================================END\n");
```

}

In the log I see:

```
=========================================will start onNavigated

And then directly:
=====================================================================
=================================SLEEP 20000====================================
```

What is strange is that I had this code in a unittest and it worked, I created a new windows phone project with a UI and it doesn't work

Comment: This is C++/CLI - an adaptation of C++ for the .NET runtime platform. Please consider creating a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) as what you posted has a low signal/noise ratio and is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was because of the ThreadSleep:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds dura(20000);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
```

In the library project where I was working I was using a different sleep, provided by the library, and that would work. So this was the line that would cause the application to block itself.
I worked my way around this by including 2 buttons in the app, for the start and stop recording.